# Website ranks on google and disappears again

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, search-results

I've created a website with WordPress about two months ago. The website mainly focuses on content writing services with up to 5 pages for different writing services & also a blog with more than 10 blog posts till now.
I've started to create backlinks and also doing some on page SEO since the first week. I've also added Sitemap to google webmaster tools, everything looks fine. Anyway, after about two months, I expected to see some serp improvements, so I've searched for the query and checked google results up to page 15 and yay! I was there. It was a good feeling as I was expecting to get better and better positions everyday. Because my website was mainly focused on the topic, whereas so many results on pages after 7, was not even 1% related to the topic.
But, suddenly my website have completely gone from the results, even not on page 20!
So I tried to figure out what is happening. I reviewed every section in webmaster tools, fixed crawl some crawl errors and started a live page test, and after that, requested indexing. In less than an hour, I was again on page 15, for a few days actually. Again, I'm not on any pages. And this cycle continues... 
I wonder if is something wrong here. I don't think that google is punishing me for building backlinks soon or something like this, because I'm on page 5 on a longtail keyword (based on the main keyword).
So what do you suggest? Should I wait? Or continue to live test & request indexing...

Comment: Sorry but the question is too specific and unlikely to help others.

Comment: But to add, its perfectly normal for a new site to bounce in and out of the rankings. do `site:https://www.example.com/` as a search instead of keywords, including `site:` and change the example with your own domain. If it appears, your indexed and ranked, just improve the rankings with time, content and visitors.